# Set theory related Question

Tags: general-topology

The set {$x\in$ $\Bbb R$ : $x$ $\sin{x}$ $\leq 1$ , $x$ $\cos{x}$ $\leq$ 1} $\subset \Bbb R$ is

1. a bounded closed set.
2. a bounded open set.
3. an unbounded closed set.
4. an unbounded open set.

My Attempt :
When we divide $x \sin{x} \leq 1$ by $x \cos{x} \leq 1$ then we get $\tan{x} \leq 1$ which is unbounded below but bounded above by 1. So this set can be written as $(-\infty,1]$. So all options discarded. Please help me what is a condition skipped by me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: $(\infty,1]$ is a closed set, though it is not $\{x\in \mathbb R: x\sin x \le 1, x\cos x \le 1\}$

Comment: For example $+10 \in \{x\in \mathbb R: x\sin x \le 1, x\cos x \le 1\}$ but $-9$ is not

Comment: How we get this set in symbolic form step by step ? I have no more information about it.

Comment: What is a reason for negative vote. Please tell me what is mistake that I can improve it.

Comment: If $\tan(x) \le 1$ you have *no* guarantee that both $x\sin x \le 1$ and $x\cos x \le 1$, so that reworking is useless. You cannot divide inequalities...

Answer (score 3):

Note that if $f(x)=x\sin x,g(x)=x\cos x$ then:

$$\{x\in\mathbb{R}:x\sin x\leq 1,x\cos x\leq 1\} = \{x\in\mathbb{R}:x\sin x\leq 1\}\cap\{x\in\mathbb{R}:x\cos x\leq 1\} = \\ f^{-1}[(-\infty,1]]\cap g^{-1}[(-\infty,1]]$$

Since $f,g$ are continuous, $f^{-1}[(-\infty,1]],g^{-1}[(-\infty,1]]$ are both closed sets, thus their intersection is closed as well.

Moreover, those sets are unbounded and share infinitely many points (for example, points of the form $x=\pi k, k\text{ is a positive odd integer}$ are roots of $f$ and $g(\pi k)<0$ so they all belong to $f^{-1}[(-\infty,1]]\cap g^{-1}[(-\infty,1]]$.

To conclude, this set is closed and unbounded.

Comment: I could not understand how you have written the 
given set as $f^{-1}(-\infty,1],g^{-1}(-\infty,1]$

Comment: By definition: $f^{-1}(A)=\{x:f(x)\in A\}$ and note that $\{x:x\sin x \leq 1\}=\{x:x\sin x\in(-\infty,1]\}$. Is it clear now?

Comment: yes. What is roster form of {$x : x sinx \in (-\infty , 1]$} and  {$x : x sinx \in (-\infty , 1]$}

Comment: @Ankit roster form?? Never heard of such a thing. $f^{-1}[A]$ is a perfectly fine way to define a set once we know $f$ and $A$.

Comment: @Henno Brandsma I have not clear the concept of unboundedness of given set.

Comment: @Ankit the answer gives an unbounded subset.

Comment: @Henno Brandsma I could not understand what you say, points of the form $x=\pi k, k\text{ is a positive odd integer}$ are roots of $f$ and $g(\pi k)<0$

Comment: @Ankit Tair said that all points $\pi, 3\pi, 5\pi,\ldots$ are in your set. So it’s clearly unbounded.

Comment: @Henno Brandsma thank you so much for clearing my doubt